# Stop a stylesheet from displaying on layers above it in a Geoserver group layer

Tags: geoserver, group-layer

Background: I have a layer group made up of a series of raster tiles of increase detail as you zoom in on the map. The issue is not all of the layers have full coverage of the map. The idea to fill in the missing area was to use the natural earth[1](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/) shapefiles to fill in the gaps. We have an OSM like style sheet that labels the states, countries, rivers, and adds state lines. This is so a user can get an idea of where they are in the map if they zoom into to the incorrect area. The only issue is the natural earth stylesheet is showing on top of the raster file when added to the group layer.

Question: Is there a way to stop a stylesheet from displaying on layers above it in a Geoserver group layer? Or would it work to call the layers separately in openlayers?

Tools: Geoserver Openlayers

Below is an exmple of the issue. This is at ~2 million scale. On the left behind the raster is the NE layer where we have missing coverage. On the right is a raster layer. As you can see on the raster are various labels created by the NE layer's stylesheet. We do not want this behavior. 
[image: Example]

Comment: did you put the natural earth layer at the bottom of the layer group?

Comment: Yes the NE layer is on the bottom.

Comment: please add a screenshot to show what is happening

Comment: Added a screen shot

Answer (score 1):

Labels will always be rendered last, this is a feature.

To prevent this you will need to request two layers separately either in OpenLayers or as a new LayerGroup containing the layer group and the NE layer.